# Capture shell call from python program

Tags: python, c++, shell

I am working on modification to the C++ "CuraEngine" which is a command line program that is called by a python gui "Cura". Cura outputs a complex string with quite a few parameters to CuraEngine and I need to figure out what exactly that is.

Is there a way to capture the entire CuraEngine shell string that Cura calls?

OS: Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 x64)
[Cura - Python](https://github.com/daid/Cura)
[CuraEngine - C++](https://github.com/Ultimaker/CuraEngine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. rename `CuraEngine` to `CuraEngine.bin`
2. create a shell script named `CuraEngine` which would save its arguments (shell variable `"$@"`), call `./CuraEngine.bin "$@"` and probably capture its output via stream redirection or `tee` program.

Comment: Much nicer than my idea.

Comment: I tried this with tee and with exec redirect and it works when I call the script in the command line but not when the Cura GUI calls it...  
exec > >(tee /home/uminded/Downloads/logfile.txt)

Comment: Well, I would suggest to check stderr as well. Is there anything in stderr when you run the script from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's python you could probably decompile it using any of the python decompilers, insert a line that logs the executed commands to a file of your choosing and then replace the .pyc with your new .py. I think things might run as usual, but you get the exact commands used.

Comment: I have never done any python coding, I figure I can just search for the CuraEngine binary in the script and dump whatever commands it used  to the shell. Is their a program you can run an app through and it will spit out the external calls? I had something like that on windows back in the days...